# how do i fetch data by id on datatable jquery (ajax) in laravel 9

Tags: jquery, laravel, datatable

> i want to send id from frontend using laravel route to controller by
> datatable jquery ajax but i dont know how to send id number to
> controller

```
var id = $("#patient_id").val();
        $('#patientPayment_table').DataTable({
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            ajax: '{{ route('patientPayment.getData','id' ) }}',
            columns: [{
                    "data": "id",
                    render: function(data, type, row, meta) {
                        return meta.row + meta.settings._iDisplayStart + 1;
                    }
                },
                {
                    data: 'debit'
                },
                {
                    data: 'credit'
                },
                {
                    data: 'date'
                },
                {
                    data: 'description'
                },
                {
                    data: 'action'
                },
            ]

        });
```